# unable to get attributes in an accessor method - laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Okay I want to have custom field that does not exist as a column in my db table.

I followed, last part :
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

My model code:

```
class Car extends Eloquent{
    protected $fillable = array('driverID', 'fuelRemaining');
    protected $appends = array('is_driver');

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }

    public function getIsDriverAttribute(){
        return ($this->attributes['driverID'] == Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

Car table:

```
Schema::create('cars', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('driverID');
        $table->integer('fuelRemaining');
        $table->mediumtext('desc');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

As you can see i want an extra field which is "is_driver" to be returned, but when I run this, this field is used to determine whether current signed in user is the driver himself by comparing the IDs.

it will output this error:

```
Undefined index: driverID
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong here, please advice.

Comment: Can you show us what your Car table looks like?

Comment: weird thing is I am able to obtain `$this->attributes['id']`

Comment: What about `$this->driverID`?

Comment: Have you seeded the table? Id there definitely a driverID in the record?

Comment: yes I have seeded. theres data. @lukasgeiter i have tried that, theres a return but I check again using var_dump $this->driverID returns NULL

Comment: its okay guys I have found the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah I have found why. This is a reference for future readers

In my controller I only get these two

```
$car = Car::where('fuelRemaining', 0)->get(array('id', 'desc'));
```

When i added authorID to the get array

```
$car = Car::where('fuelRemaining', 0)->get(array('id', 'desc', 'authorID'));
```

I am able to get the authorID attribute in my custom accessor mentioned in the question.